# Exporting 500,000 records from Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I export about 500,000 records from within SQL developer ? I am trying to export but it is crashing when i highlight the results to then export..

Comment: you don't need to highlight anything, and what type of export are you trying to do? in version 3.2 exporting that many rows to Excel will prob run into memory issues. Go get version 4.0 or higher and use the XLSX format - assuming that's what you want

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click in the [Query Result].
2. Choose the export option.
3. Choose the appropriate options.
4. [Next]
5. [Finish]

Unless you are using SQL Developer V1 against Oracle V7, then you might have problems; but you didn't offer version info, so ...

Or are these the steps you have tried?

Comment: i am using version 3.2. perhaps why im having the export  problem

Comment: Are you saying you have exactly followed those steps, or the instructions posted by Hernandez, and are still having the problem?

Comment: i followed the steps and there was no sucess. I do not believe my version of SQL developer allows me to export more than 200,000 records.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are attempting to export to a single file and not to the clipboard.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes i am exporting to a file and not a clipboard.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to highlight in order to export, just right-click on the first result SQLDeveloper presents (first 50 rows of your query) and then export option.[image]

Then a Wizard to choose file and other options will appear.

[image]